Light Settings Issue
I would like to see this:

But instead I see this:

Any suggestions?

Hello, have you selected the light? Could you please show the whole interface?

You have to 1) select the light to make sure you can change the light settings and 2) go to the Light Properties tab (the green bulb) which would be further down than your screenshot shows if you have a light selected. Right now you are in the Tool settings tab (the screwdriver and wrench symbol).

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

The green light bulb was the issue. Thank you!
